# Electron.NET ServiceController Starting a windows service via backend

Tags: c#, electron, .net-6.0, servicecontroller, electron.net

I built an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app and was able to successfully build and run it as an electron app. Part of my app's UI hits a controller endpoint solely to start/stop a companion Windows Service.

I am receiving the below error message when doing so. I confirmed my service name matches in the service console vs in my code so the error message doesn't make a ton of sense. I did confirm this works as expected running as a standard web app.

Any ideas if this is possible in this way or do I need to open up an IPC channel to do this functionality?

```
public IActionResult StartService()
{
     try
     {
         using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("SERVICENAME"))
         {
             if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
             {
                 serviceController.Start();
                 serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
             }
         }
    
         return Content("Service started");
    
     } catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return Content($"Error starting service: {ex}");
     }
}
    
public IActionResult StopService()
{
     try
     {
         using (ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("SERVICENAME"))
         {
             if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
             {
                 serviceController.Stop();
                 serviceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    
             }
         }
         return Content("Service stopped");
     } 
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return Content($"Error stopping service: {ex}");
     }
}
```

Here is the error message returned in electron dev console

> Error starting service: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service 'SERVICENAME' on computer '.'.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(:8001/String[] args)
> at :8001/System.Service…Controller.Start()
> at :8001/PROJECT.Cont…troller.cs:line 207